# Are == and != operators compiler-generated?

Tags: c++, equals-operator

Do I need to provide == and/or != operators? I've read here: [Why don't C++ compilers define operator== and operator!=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/why-dont-c-compilers-define-operator-and-operator) that I do but when I actually tried it (didn't provide them and tried to use them) the program compiled fine. So what's going on?

Using VS2010 if it matters.

Comment: Think this is a C++11 feature so need newish compiler.

Comment: Are you sure it's a class comparision?

Comment: How about showing us your code? It's hard to guess what you have done as my crystal ball broke just the other day ;)

Answer (score 1):

These operators are defined for fundamental, language-defined types, not for your custom ones. So it will work for `int`s, for example. But won't for `class foo;` unless you provide them explicitly - compiler doesn't know **how** to compare your own defined types if you haven't told it how to do it.

Comment: Aren't these defined for floating-point numbers and pointers as well?

Comment: @H2CO3 sure. `int` was an example

Comment: @icepack: but you said "for integral types", and floating-point types and pointers are not integral. :)