# Equality check for objects of classes with explicit constructor only

Tags: c++, equality

Why can I not check two objects of classes with explicit constructor only for equality? The following code does [not compile](http://ideone.com/2sV05I)

```
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}
    int x_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo(1) == Foo(1);
}
```

Do I have to declare `operator ==` explicitly?

Comment: Because you didn't show the compiler how to compare them.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought it would have something to do with the ctor being `explicit`, but I just learned, C++ does not create `operator ==` by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/why-dont-c-compilers-define-operator-and-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload the equality `operator==`:

```
struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}
    int x_;
};

bool operator==(Foo const &lhs, Foo const& rhs) { return lhs.x_ == rhs.x_; }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9085c38441d6ef2f)

Comment: I'd recommend making `operator==` a non-member so it treats its arguments symmetrically.

Comment: @101010 I didn't mean the `const`, I meant if any implicit conversions were added later, the lhs would be treated differently from the rhs. With the code written as is, it doesn't make a difference, but I tend to write all relational operators as non-members for consistency.

Comment: See [this useful guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) on how best to declare operator overloads. As @TartanLlama points out, `operator==` is best declared as a non-member method, as it treats both operands equally.

Comment: @LogicStuff Nothing wrong I misread the comment of TartanLlama. Thanks for the edit though, it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

How shoud compiler know how it should compare them? Either define `operator==` or use `Foo(1).x_ == Foo(1).x_` if you want to compare those ints.

Maybe you misunderstood what `explicit` constructor means. It's about asignment operator `=` and not comparism. Marking your constructor `explicits` disables following snippet to compile: `Foo f = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler does not generate equality for you, so you have to do it yourself. This isn't about explicit constructors either; at no point has C++ ever allowed comparing classes or structs implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an operator == like that:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& f) { return x_==f.x_; }
```