# The equality operator (==) in my class is not working

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, equality-operator

I have been following some cpp exercises to learn cpp and I've run into a problem.

I've created a class called "FixedPoint2" to implement a fixed point number to 2 decimals. I've included the header file which includes all the functions below.

What I am struggling with is that when I try to test out the equality operator, I always get a false answer. In other words the following happens:

```
cout << (FixedPoint2(1.0)==FixedPoint2(1.0)) << endl; //returns true as expected
cout << (FixedPoint2(1.2)==FixedPoint2(1.2)) << endl; //returns false
cout << FixedPoint2(1.2) << "\t" << FixedPoint2(1.2) << endl; returns 1.2 1.2
```

So you get the idea. I have also tested it with if-statements to make sure my overloaded call out is not the problem. For example:

```
if (FixedPoint2(4.5)==FixedPoint2(4.5)) 
    cout << "Don't post to stackoverflow"; //This doesn't print
```

My intuition tells me something is up with with either some implicit type conversion I have overlooked, or some messy things within double. But I don't think either of those is it.

```
using namespace std;


class FixedPoint2
{
    private:
        int16_t m_digi; //chosen because I want the range
        int8_t m_deci; //chosen to optimise memory 
    public:
        FixedPoint2(int16_t digi = 0, int8_t deci = 0):m_digi{digi}, m_deci{deci}
        {
            assert(!(deci>127 || deci<-127)); //to prevent overflows
            if(deci<-100 || deci>100) //just in case some moron (me) does some weird decimal calculations 
            {
                m_digi+=(static_cast<int16_t>(deci)/100);
                m_deci+=(-100);
            }
        }
    FixedPoint2(double mydouble) 
    {
        if (mydouble>=0) //The if-else floors the absolute value of the integer base
        {
            m_digi=static_cast<int16_t>(floor(mydouble));
        }
        else
        {
            m_digi=static_cast<int16_t>(floor(mydouble)+1);
        }
        m_deci=static_cast<int8_t>(round(100*(mydouble-m_digi))); //This rounds off the decimal to two digits

    };

    operator double();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const FixedPoint2 &f1);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, FixedPoint2 &f1);
    friend FixedPoint2 operator+(const FixedPoint2 &f1, const FixedPoint2 &f2);
};

FixedPoint2::operator double()
{
    double base= static_cast<double>(m_digi);
    double decimal= static_cast<double>(m_deci);
    return base+0.01*decimal;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const FixedPoint2 &f1)
{
    FixedPoint2 a=f1;
    out << double(a); //this is an easy work around to handling the period placement for the fixed point number
    return out;
}


istream& operator>>(istream &in, FixedPoint2 &f1)
{
    double placeholder;
    in>>placeholder;
    f1=FixedPoint2(placeholder);
    return in;
}

FixedPoint2 operator+(const FixedPoint2 &f1, const FixedPoint2 &f2)
{
    return FixedPoint2(f1.m_digi+f2.m_digi, f1.m_deci+f2.m_deci);
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Where is your overload of `operator==`?

Comment: @c650 I think he's getting by on the `operator double();` converting and comparing doubles, which could make it a case of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) but we also don't have `FixedPoint` defined so what do I know?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll follow the protocol next time. I solved this one today as per the suggestion of a friend of mine. The problem was that the == operator not being overloaded. I don't know why this would cause an error though. Any insights?

Comment: @user4581301 Ah sorry! all instances are of the FixedPoint2 class. There is no FixedPoint class in my code.

Comment: @c650 I deliberately has refrained from including this because I thought that it would default to memberwise comparison. It didn't and this was the problem. I've fixed it now. But do you have any idea why it doesn't default to memberwise comparison?

Comment: @A.Far there is no default `operator==` for classes in C++

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not automatically generate `operator==` because odds are really good that it will get it wrong a lot more often than it gets it right. Let's take a simple example: a dynamic string. The compiler would generate code that compared character by character, right? When does it stop? Now the compiler needs to know more about the programmer's intent with their string, and the compiler doesn't need the extra complexity of a telepathic interface.

Better to have on consistent rule, no, and force an explicit definition of what is to be compared than a minefield of crap code resulting from people assuming they got what they wanted. Longer discussion on the topic here: [Why don't C++ compilers define operator== and operator!=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/why-dont-c-compilers-define-operator-and-operator)

The compiler looks around for a way to satisfy the comparison. It doesn't find a direct `operator==`, but it does find `operator double` and `double`s can be used for the compare. Except sometimes they can't: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

That said I'm unable to reproduce OP's results. I would expect the exact same formula to execute on the exact same input to get the exact same result, even if that result is 1.199999... rather than 1.2

While I cannot reproduce, OP is still better off implementing the fixed point `operator==` because there is no imprecision with a fixed point number. Fixed point will be equal or not equal, no ifs ands or buts, so "Nothing can go wrong!" Plus, this operator should be trivial to write. Something like `return (rhs.m_digi == lhs.m_digi) && (rhs.m_deci == lhs.m_deci);`