# std::tuple member by member comparison fails

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I wanted to test [this very interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127907/8873508) and came out with this minimal implementation:

```
class A
{
    enum M { a };
    std::tuple<int> members;

public:

    A() { std::get<M::a>(members) = 0; }
    A(int value) { std::get<M::a>(members) = value; }
    A(const A & other) { members = other.members; }

    int get() const { return std::get<M::a>(members); }

    bool operator==(A & other) { return members == other.members; }
};
```

and a simple test:

```
int main() {

    A x(42);
    A y(x);

    std::cout << (x==y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Everything's fine, until I define a simple `struct B {};` and try to add an instance of it as a member. As soon as I write

```
std::tuple<int, B> members;
```

the `operator==` isn't ok anymore and I get this message from the compiler (gcc 5.4.1):

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::__tuple_element_t<1ul, std::tuple<int, B> > {aka const B}’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<1ul, std::tuple<int, B> > {aka const B}’)
  return bool(std::get<__i>(__t) == std::get<__i>(__u))
                                 ^
```

I tried providing an `operator==` to `B`:

```
struct B
{
    bool operator==(const B &){ return true; }
};
```

and had an extra from compiler:

```
candidate: bool B::operator==(const B&) <near match>
     bool operator==(const B &){ return true; }
          ^
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with B struct? Is it lacking something, or else?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "without luck"? Since the error message complains about not finding a `operator==(const B&, const B&)` adding it seems obvious. The question probably should be why it isn't found, but you need to change your question code for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ultimately const correctness. You didn't const qualify `B`'s (or `A`'s, for that matter) comparison operator and its parameter consistently.

Since [tuple's `operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) accepts by a const reference, it cannot use your const-incorrect implementation. And overload resolution fails as a consequence.

Tidying up all of those const qualifiers [resolves all the errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ztnDznyryTDQMruF).