# Why do we need the spaceship <=> operator in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Why do we need such an operator in C++ and how is it useful in modern C++ programming? Any real world code examples where this can be applied will help.

This question is geared to **understanding the practical application** in the real world.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485803/how-and-why-did-the-iso-c-standards-committee-wg21-decide-to-accept-the-prop

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll give you three points of motivation, just off the top of my head:

1. It's the common generalization of all other comparison operator (for totally-ordered domains): `>`, `>=`, `==`, `<=`, `<` . Using `<=>` (spaceship), you can implement each of these other operations in a completely generic way.
2. For strings, it's equivalent to the good old `strcmp()` function from the C standard library. So - useful for lexicographic order checks, such as data in vectors or lists or other ordered containers.
3. For integral numbers, it's what the hardware does anyway: On `x86` or `x86_64` Comparing a and b (`CMP RAX, RBX`) is basically like subtracting (`SUB RAX, RBX`) except that `RAX` doesn't actually change, only the flags are affected, so you can use "jump on equal/not equal/greater than/lesser than/etc." (JE/JNE/JGT/JLT etc.) as the next instruction. `CMP` should be thought of as a "spaceship compare".

Comment: Yeah, but why add an operator and complicate the grammar - which is already an unparseable mess as it is? Just create a `std::compare` working in a similar way as `std::hash` - already provided for builtin types, user definable for custom types.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: 1. It doesn't complicate parsing the grammar. The C++ grammar has a ambiguity issues, this isn't one of them. 2. This is part of a grander scheme of things which will include compiler-generated [default comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) for most types, which will be _awesome_.

Comment: Also, point 3 is a bit of a moot point - current compilers already optimize without problems sequences of comparisons regarding the same values.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: about point 3 - not moot, in the same sense that you don't need >= since you have > and =. If the hardware does >=, why shouldn't you be able to say that?

Comment: 1. It's extra syntax, it complicates the grammar. If it can be done without any particular problem with existing syntax, generally you don't want to touch it. 2. So what? Range-based `for` already knows about `begin` and `end`, what would be the problem in letting compiler-generated operators know about `compare`?

Comment: You got it reversed. You don't have `<=` because the hardware knows how to do `<=`, you have `<=` because it's an operator that often comes useful when writing code. The compiler then maps it on the underlying hardware the best it can.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: C++ did not invent the 3-way comparison spaceship operator. Other languages did. C++ is merely adopting it in a C++ form. There's no reason for C++ to spell it `compare` when we can just spell it the way everyone else does.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*what would be the problem in letting compiler-generated operators know about compare?*" There's a huge difference between range-based `for` doing ADL lookup on `begin` and canonizing a name (which is common enough to already be in use by many other people) with an `= default` implementation and special language meaning. I'll take the minor grammar "complication" of <=> over breaking tons of code by potentially changing the meaning of every `compare` function that someone has written.

Comment: @NicolBolas: disputable; Python calls it `cmp`; OCaml and Haskell call it `compare`; Java calls it `compareTo`. But ok, it's an operator because someone liked how it looked, not because there's some technical reason why it couldn't be implemented otherwise. That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*it's an operator because someone liked how it looked, not because there's some technical reason why it couldn't be implemented otherwise*" If you wish to pretend that's the case, you can do so. It doesn't make what I said about existing `compare` functions any less true. `operator<=>` has the advantage of having no existing functions to conflict with.

Comment: @NicolBolas: with this kind of reasoning we'd need a new operator for any customization point; I don't expect `compare` to be any more common than - say - `hash`. But you could call it any other way - say, `three_way_compare`; or just ignore ADL and require a template specialization straight into `std` (which would solve the conflict problem once for all). Again, the point is, it's not like it couldn't be done without a grammar modification, it just looks better this way. I'm fine with it, I'm just trying to understand the rationale.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: 1. (About your earlier comment regarding hardware capabilities) Sometimes hardware capabilities inspire programming language structures, sometimes it's the other way around. 2. I disagree that if something can be done with existing syntax, you generally don't want to touch it. It's not that the current syntax of C++ is held to be pure and perfect. It's kind of a work-in-progress. Some stuff gets added, occasionally a few things get removed.

Comment: @einpoklum: I'm quite sure that the spaceship operators doesn't arise out of hardware capabilities; it comes out from the need of compactly provide an all-in-one comparison function, and the `<=>` syntax and name actually comes from Perl, which is definitely as far away from hardware as a language can be. Also, intrinsics - which are arguably the part of C and C++ implementations that is nearest to the hardware - are normally provided as functions or function-like macros; operators are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: As for the "don't touch the core language if it's not necessary" part, it's just that it's the general attitude used so far in the development of the C++ language, and for a good reason; introducing syntax (and in general, modifications to the core language) is way more cumbersome than adding parts of the library. It breaks compatibility (I'll have to add `#ifdef` in class libraries around `operator<=>`, and the implementation will need to avoid it anyway), it is more difficult to test in existing implementations, it's impossible to backport. Library-only changes are more convenient.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I feel your pain... Remember, though, that my answer gave potential motivation that springs to my mind, not the choices of the standards committee.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*Library-only changes are more convenient.*" And yet less useful. Without any core language changes, `= default` comparison generation would not be possible. And without *that*, then the ability to put user-defined types in template parameters (something that is being added for C++20) would not be possible. This is no different from rvalue references; you *could* have made that some kind of standard library type that language features could key off of, but then we wouldn't be able to use it to fix forwarding.

Comment: Why would it not be possible to have user-defined types in template parameters without compiler-generated comparisons? Don't you mean it would be problematic?

Comment: @Moia: I respectfully disagree, as does OP.

Comment: @einpoklum sorry, I meant code example not explanation

Comment: @MatteoItalia I think it would be cool to have a `hash` operator. Just like Nim enables sigil as function names. you could say `#var` to mean `std::hash(var)` and `<-var` to say `std::move(var)`. These are all liberties you can take in Nim. (or almost; because sigils are actually quite limited)