# default comparator for C++ struct

Tags: c++, stl

When using C++ STL, we often need to compare the elements in a container, such as `set`, `sort`, `priority_queue`. My question is, when i define a new type of struct (or class, doesn't matter) without specifying any comparator or operator overloading, and somehow compare two struct objects, **how will C++ compare them by default**? E.g. by the value of address, or consider the whole struct as a big number, or use the lower four bytes? Or something else?

Comment: Why don’t you try it? Granted, trying something is often not a good way to get an authoritative answer in C++ (due to undefined and implementation-defined behaviour) but in this case it works just fine.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why don't C++ compilers define operator== and operator!=?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217911/10871073).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, I tried, but I still couldn't see the logic how C++ sort the structs.

Comment: @Neo That’s confusing: you should be getting a descriptive *compilation error*. Please share your code.