# Why is my variable constant when it wasn't when I defined it?

Tags: c++, vector

Currently, I have a problem when trying to find a variable within a `vector`.
I defined a `vector`, `tests`, set to contain my own structure `Test`. It contains two variables, `one` and `two`. Both are instances of `Test`.

`Test` isn't much, it only contains an `int` and `char`.

I defined a macro that finds wether or not an instance of an object is in a given `vector` or not.

When I attempt to compile my code, it results in this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Test*, std::vector<Test> >; _Value = const Test]':
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1932:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Test*, std::vector<Test> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const Test>]'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1977:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Test*, std::vector<Test> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const Test>]'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3902:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Test*, std::vector<Test> >; _Tp = Test]'
test.cpp:19:6:   required from here
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:268:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Test' and 'const Test')
  268 |  { return *__it == _M_value; }
      |
```

What I find interesting is that the variable I am checking is considered constant, even though when I defined it, it wasn't.

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define isin(one, two) (std::find(one.begin(), one.end(), two) != one.end())

struct Test {
    int one;
    char two;
};

int main() {
    Test one = { 6, 'n' };
    Test two = { 9, 'r' };

    std::vector<Test> tests = { one, two };

    if (isin(tests, one)) {
        std::cout << "one is in tests\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "one is not in tests\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `one` considered constant? Did I accidentally do something wrong?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have no `operator==`. Why you're using a macro for this is beyond me.

Comment: It's easier to understand the intent of a call like `if (isin(haystack, needle)) {..}`  than `if (std::find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle) != haystack.end()) {...}`, but it would be much safer (and due to function-inlining, equally runtime-efficient) to implement that syntactic sugar by writing a function instead of a macro.

Comment: On the `const` Good style says start with the most restrictive and work your way out to least restrictive as options get eliminated. Since there is no good reason for an `==` operator to change either of the arguments, `const` is the right place to start. The canonical `==` operator looks something like `bool operator==(const TYPE & lhs, const TYPE & rhs)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Test' and 'const Test')
> ```

You don't have an equality operator defined for `Test`. You need to define `operator==` so it can know how to check if two instances are equal.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that there is no `operator==` defined that can compare a non-const `Test` object on the left to a `const Test` object on the right.  The compiler [does not generate a default `operator==` for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/) (though, this is actually [addressed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons), though it is not automatic, you still have to request it explicitly).

The 2nd `Test` in the error message is `const` because that is how [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is taking it in:

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value )
```

`std::find()` iterates the specified range comparing `value` to each element in the range using `operator==`, similar to this:

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value )
{
    while (first != last) {
        if (*first == value) { // <-- here
            return first;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return last;
}
```

In this case, `T` is `Test`, so `value` is `const Test &value`.  `tests` is a non-const `std::vector<Test>`, so its iterators refer to non-const `Test` elements.  But the `value` being compared to them is a `const Test`.

You need to define an `operator==` for `Test` that can handle that comparison, eg:

```cpp
struct Test {
    int one;
    char two;

    bool operator==(const Test &rhs) const {
        return one == rhs.one && two == rhs.two;
        /* alternatively:
        return std::tie(one, two) == std::tie(rhs.one, rhs.two);
        */
    }

    /* alternatively in C++20 onwards:
    bool operator==(const Test &) const = default;  
    */
};
```