# Define 'operator<', constructors for a tuple-style struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

For a 'tuple-style' C++ struct, such as

```
struct state {
  int a, b, c;
};
```

how can we most quickly `operator<` and constructors with natural semantics (e.g. similar to those of `std::pair`)?

Specifically, is there a way to obtain the following methods without explicitly writing the implementation?

```
struct state {
    int a, b, c;
    state() { }  // a = b = c = 0
    state(int _a, int _b, int _c) {  } // a = _a, b = _b, c = _c

    bool operator<(const state& other) const {
        // first compare by a, then by b, then by c
        return (a == other.a ? (b == other.b ? (c < other.c) : b < other.b) : a < other.a)
    }
};
```

More generally, does any approach for when the fields are not all of the same type? For example,

```
struct state {
    int a, b;
    string c;
};
```

Comment: What version of C++ are you using? Also, is it really "tuple-style" if you can't get the elements with `std::get`?

Comment: The dupe is for `operator ==` but the code is the same for `operator <`, you just have to replace the `==`'s with `<`'s

Comment: Extra to the dupe, there is the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Comment: @NathanOliver what about constructors?

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27837789/4342498) for C++20 default comparison options.

Comment: @AustinBest For the default, you can use in class initializers: `int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;`.  For the parameterized constructor no.  That said, if you get rid of all the constructors your class becomes an aggregate and can be initialized like `state foo{1, 2, 3}`